How do I identify the carbonyl atoms in a PDB file
Can I infer it from the atom name alone? Or do I need to look at the structure of the residue it is in?

Can you add background to your research, why you need to know, and explain what PDB is?

PDB is a file format that was used with the Protein Data Bank to record information on the position and relations of atoms in a molecule.

Looking at the ATOM records for an Ala residue, as an example:

ATOM    132  N   ALA A  33       0.179 -33.349   1.978  1.00 18.93           N
ATOM    133  CA  ALA A  33       0.316 -32.425   0.863  1.00 21.72           C
ATOM    134  C   ALA A  33      -0.617 -32.824  -0.275  1.00 24.91           C
ATOM    135  O   ALA A  33      -0.538 -33.915  -0.831  1.00 23.04           O
ATOM    136  CB  ALA A  33       1.764 -32.365   0.428  1.00 15.90           C

I've bolded the name field. The carbonyl carbon is designated C and the carbonyl oxygen is designated O. See here for a note on nomenclature:

Atoms names follow the recommendations of described in Pure & Appl. Chem., 70, 117-142, 199

And from that IUPAC publication:

In the peptide backbone, the nitrogen is denoted by N, its attached hydrogen by H, and the carbonyl carbon and oxygen by C and 0, respectively (ref. 20).

